# R: ggplot stacked barplot where bar height corresponds to largest value

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))    
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity")

> df2
  supp dose  len
1   VC D0.5  6.8
2   VC   D1 15.0
3   VC   D2 33.0
4   OJ D0.5  4.2
5   OJ   D1 10.0
6   OJ   D2 29.5
```

[image]

Here, the height of each bar corresponds to the sum of `len` of the 2 `supp` groups. I want the height of the bar to correspond to the larger of the 2 `len` values. For instance, the height of the `D0.5` bar should be 6.8, and that of `D` should be 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter by `max` of `len` by `dose` first.

```
df2 %>% group_by(dose) %>%
  filter(len == max(len)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

---

### Edit

Ah, it seems like you are looking for `position_dodge()`:

```
df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0))
```

[image]

You can adjust the width of the bars by specifying the `width` in `geom_bar` (say, `width = 1.5`).

Comment: I still want a stacked barplot (i.e. I want the other `supp` group to show up on the plot too, not just the `supp` group with the max dose).

Comment: @Adrian, I misunderstood your question. See if my edit now solves your problem.